# how can i call a overriden method of the super class?

Tags: java, methods, overriding

how can i call a overriden method of the super class?
for example:

```
  class A {
        public void someMethod() {
            // someMethod of class A
        }
    }


    class B extends A {
        public void someMethod() {
            //someMethod of class B.
            // How to call to the someMethod of class A
        }
    }
```

I overriden the someMethod of class A, how can i still call it from the someMethod of A?

Comment: ..So to be fair with newbies, in that case they should also downvote duplicate answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `super` keyword to access the overridden method in the direct superclass, in B:

```
super.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call super.someMethod();

Answer (score 0):

Use `super` keyword

```
super.Methodname()
```

Comment: Should be `super` and not `Super` with a capital `S`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
super.someMethod();
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `super`

 FYI visit [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) to understand with example.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, still call it from the someMethod "of B"? Use:

```
super.someMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the Object of A class.

```
A a= new A();
a.someMethod();
```